# Filer divs id as you type (existing example needs two tweaks)

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I'm trying to get some functionality in place for filtering some divs based on what you are typing. I have have found an example that I need some help with tweaking.

```
<div id="banana, apple">Fruits</div>
<div id="tomato, cucumber">Vegetables</div>
<div id="banana, apple, tomato">Mix</div>
<input type="text" name="search">

$('input').bind('keyup',function(){
   var selfVal = $(this).val()
   var compareDivs = $('div');
    compareDivs.each(function(){
       var divVal = $(this).text().toString();
        console.log(divVal);
       if (divVal.indexOf(selfVal)<0)
           $(this).fadeOut();
        else
            $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQFQ5/33/

The filtering should be done by looking in the div's id. So when I search for the word "banana", then "Fruits" and "Mix" should show up.

Would higly appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 var divVal = $(this).text().toString();
```

You need to get the

```
 var divVal = $(this).attr('id');
```

Because you looking for the id value, not for the text.

Look this working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HQFQ5/34/

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you Nahum! Just one follow up questions: This will filter all div's on my page. Can I select which div's this should apply to somehow?

Comment: Just give them a unique class and select it instead of select 'div'. i.e. var compareDivs = $('.YOUR-AWESOME-UNIQUE-CLASS').